# How to prove R value for insulation?

Tags: thermodynamics, home-experiment, thermal-conductivity, insulators

I ran some tests on different types of insulation. I heated water, and placed it into an insulated box. The temperature was recorded every minute, for the water, as well as the air. The insulation which is the best (high [R value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_%28insulation%29)) will have the temperature drop the least. I have calculated the heat added using:

$$Q~=~mc\Delta T.$$

Is this right, or should I have down something different?

Can the laws of Thermodynamics be used?

Comment: There are established methods for doing this: is there any particular reason why you're not following them? Knowing the answer to that will help us help you. Have you come across the concepts of emissivity and boundary layers?

Comment: I haven't looked up other people methods. And I have not come accross emissivity and boundary layers.

Comment: You're not from Australia by any chance? Standards here don't seem to have any knowledge of heat transfer other than by convection: no one understands radiative transfer here (as my partner found out when she tried to design the best roofing scheme for our house to turn back solar heat in the Summer and could only find R values of insulation documented). This might explain why you haven't come across emissivity.

Comment: Can the laws of Thermodynamics be used?

Comment: @TheOkayMan Of course they can. It's simply that building and other engineering standards are not worded to be understood in terms of physical laws, they are worded to be a readily implemented "recipe" assuming the reader's reasonable intelligence (mostly) without burdening the reader with the need to learn too much specialist machinery. The [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_%28insulation%29) on R-values relates $R$ to the more fundamental conductivity. And $R$ is all about and only about conduction. This is OK in some cases; but if you are trying to insulate ...

Comment: ...something against solar heat loading, radiation, emissivity and the dynamics of complex layered systems: insulation, air roof cavity, conduction through the roof skin, convection away from the skin with its associated boundary layers and emissivity of the skin all bear vitally on the total insulation effect. So you may need to describe what exactly you are trying to do to get further help. Personally, I wouldn't hazard an answer and would advise looking at the right engineering standard: these systems are so complex that semi-empirical methods, with long histories, are paramount.

Comment: If you heated the same amount of water to the same temperature each time, then whichever insulation results in the highest water temperature after 5 minutes is the best insulator... am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use $ \Delta T $ and graph that. The insulation which has the lowest value will be the best thermal resistance. Energy efficiency and added heat cannot be used in this situation.